# Keras: NaN Training Loss After Introducing Batch Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

The goal of the model is to categorically classify video sequences, where each input is a grayscale, 45-frame, 100x150 video sequence (1, 45, 100, 150), which corresponds to a one-hot encoded categorical output for one of 3 classes e.g. [0, 0, 1]. Here is the script used to train the model:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling3D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.preprocessing.image import random_rotation, random_shift, random_shear, random_zoom
from keras.regularizers import WeightRegularizer
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.utils.io_utils import HDF5Matrix
from pprint import pprint
from random import shuffle
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
K.set_image_dim_ordering("th")

import cv2
import h5py
import json
import os
import sys
import numpy as np


class OpticalSpeechRecognizer(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, frames_per_sequence, samples_generated_per_sample, config_file, training_save_fn, osr_save_fn):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.frames_per_sequence = frames_per_sequence
        self.samples_generated_per_sample = samples_generated_per_sample
        self.config_file = config_file
        self.training_save_fn = training_save_fn
        self.osr_save_fn = osr_save_fn
        self.osr = None

    def save_osr_model(self):
        """ Save the OSR model to an HDF5 file 
        """
        # delete file if it already exists
        try:
            print "Saved file \"{0}\" already exists! Overwriting previous saved file.\n".format(self.osr_save_fn)
            os.remove(self.osr_save_fn)
        except OSError:
            pass

        print "Saving OSR model to \"{0}\"".format(self.osr_save_fn)
        self.osr.save(self.osr_save_fn)

    def load_osr_model(self):
        """ Load the OSR model from an HDF5 file
        """
        print "Loading OSR model from \"{0}\"".format(self.osr_save_fn)
        self.osr = load_model(self.osr_save_fn)

    def train_osr_model(self):
        """ Train the optical speech recognizer
        """
        print "\nTraining OSR"
        validation_ratio = 0.3
        batch_size = 10
        training_sequence_generator = self.generate_training_sequences(batch_size=batch_size)
        validation_sequence_generator = self.generate_training_sequences(batch_size=batch_size, validation_ratio=validation_ratio)

        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
            sample_count = training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"]
            pbi = ProgressDisplay()
            self.osr.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence_generator,
                                   validation_data=validation_sequence_generator,
                                   samples_per_epoch=sample_count,
                                   nb_val_samples=int(round(validation_ratio*sample_count)),
                                   nb_epoch=10,
                                   max_q_size=1,
                                   verbose=2,
                                   callbacks=[pbi],
                                   class_weight=None,
                                   nb_worker=1)

    def generate_training_sequences(self, batch_size, validation_ratio=0):
        """ Generates training sequences from HDF5 file on demand
        """
        while True:
            with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
                sample_count = int(training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"])
                sample_idxs = range(0, sample_count)
                shuffle(sample_idxs)
                training_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[0:int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count)]
                validation_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count):]

                # generate sequences for validation
                if validation_ratio:
                    validation_sample_count = len(validation_sample_idxs)
                    batches = int(validation_sample_count/batch_size)
                    remainder_samples = validation_sample_count%batch_size
                    # generate batches of samples
                    for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                        X = training_save_file["X"][validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        yield (X, Y)
                    # send remainder samples as one batch, if there are any
                    if remainder_samples:
                        X = training_save_file["X"][validation_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][validation_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        yield (X, Y)

                # generate sequences for training
                else:
                    training_sample_count = len(training_sample_idxs)
                    batches = int(training_sample_count/batch_size)
                    remainder_samples = training_sample_count%batch_size
                    # generate batches of samples
                    for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                        X = training_save_file["X"][training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        yield (X, Y)
                    # send remainder samples as one batch, if there are any
                    if remainder_samples:
                        X = training_save_file["X"][training_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][training_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        yield (X, Y)

    def print_osr_summary(self):
        """ Prints a summary representation of the OSR model
        """
        print "\n*** MODEL SUMMARY ***"
        self.osr.summary()

    def generate_osr_model(self):
        """ Builds the optical speech recognizer model
        """
        print "".join(["\nGenerating OSR model\n",
                       "-"*40])
        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
            class_count = len(training_save_file.attrs["training_classes"].split(","))

        osr = Sequential()
        print " - Adding convolution layers"
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=32,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              input_shape=(1, self.frames_per_sequence, self.rows, self.columns),
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(BatchNormalization())
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=64,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(BatchNormalization())
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=128,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(BatchNormalization())
        osr.add(Flatten())
        print " - Adding fully connected layers"
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=128,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="relu"))
        osr.add(BatchNormalization())
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=128,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="relu"))
        osr.add(BatchNormalization())
        osr.add(Dropout(0.5))
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=class_count,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="softmax"))
        print " - Compiling model"
        optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.002,
                          beta_1=0.9,
                          beta_2=0.999,
                          epsilon=1e-08,
                          schedule_decay=0.004)
        osr.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                    optimizer=optimizer,
                    metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
        self.osr = osr
        print " * OSR MODEL GENERATED * "

    def process_training_data(self):
        """ Preprocesses training data and saves them into an HDF5 file
        """
        # load training metadata from config file
        training_metadata = {}
        training_classes = []
        with open(self.config_file) as training_config:
            training_metadata = json.load(training_config)
            training_classes = sorted(list(training_metadata.keys()))

            print "".join(["\n",
                           "Found {0} training classes!\n".format(len(training_classes)),
                           "-"*40])
            for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
                print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<30s}".format(class_label, training_class, training_metadata[training_class])
            print ""

        # count number of samples
        sample_count = 0
        sample_count_by_class = [0]*len(training_classes)
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            # get training class sequeunce paths
            training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
            training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                             for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                             if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                 and ".mov" in file_name)]
            # update sample count
            sample_count += len(training_class_sequence_paths)
            sample_count_by_class[class_label] = len(training_class_sequence_paths)

        print "".join(["\n",
                       "Found {0} training samples!\n".format(sample_count),
                       "-"*40])
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<6d}".format(class_label, training_class, sample_count_by_class[class_label])
        print ""

        # initialize HDF5 save file, but clear older duplicate first if it exists
        try:
            print "Saved file \"{0}\" already exists! Overwriting previous saved file.\n".format(self.training_save_fn)
            os.remove(self.training_save_fn)
        except OSError:
            pass

        # process and save training data into HDF5 file
        print "Generating {0} samples from {1} samples via data augmentation\n".format(sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample,
                                                                                       sample_count)
        sample_count = sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample
        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "w") as training_save_file:
            training_save_file.attrs["training_classes"] = np.string_(",".join(training_classes))
            training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"] = sample_count
            x_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("X", 
                                                                  shape=(sample_count, 1, self.frames_per_sequence, self.rows, self.columns),
                                                                  dtype="f")
            y_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("Y",
                                                                   shape=(sample_count, len(training_classes)),
                                                                   dtype="i")

            # iterate through each class data
            sample_idx = 0
            for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
                # get training class sequeunce paths
                training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
                training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                                 for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                                 if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                     and ".mov" in file_name)]
                # iterate through each sequence
                for idx, training_class_sequence_path in enumerate(training_class_sequence_paths):
                    sys.stdout.write("Processing training data for class \"{0}\": {1}/{2} sequences\r"
                                     .format(training_class, idx+1, len(training_class_sequence_paths)))
                    sys.stdout.flush()

                    # accumulate samples and labels
                    samples_batch = self.process_frames(training_class_sequence_path)
                    label = [0]*len(training_classes)
                    label[class_label] = 1

                    for sample in samples_batch:
                        x_training_dataset[sample_idx] = sample
                        y_training_dataset[sample_idx] = label

                        # update sample index
                        sample_idx += 1

                print "\n"

            training_save_file.close()

            print "Training data processed and saved to {0}".format(self.training_save_fn)

    def process_frames(self, video_file_path):
        """ Preprocesses sequence frames
        """
        # haar cascades for localizing oral region
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')

        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
        success, frame = video.read()

        frames = []
        success = True

        # convert to grayscale, localize oral region, equalize frame dimensions, and accumulate valid frames 
        while success:
          success, frame = video.read()
          if success:
            # convert to grayscale
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # localize single facial region
            faces_coords = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
            if len(faces_coords) == 1:
              face_x, face_y, face_w, face_h = faces_coords[0]
              frame = frame[face_y:face_y + face_h, face_x:face_x + face_w]

              # localize oral region
              mouth_coords = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
              threshold = 0
              for (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h) in mouth_coords:
                if (mouth_y > threshold):
                    threshold = mouth_y
                    valid_mouth_coords = (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h)
                else:
                    pass
              mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h = valid_mouth_coords
              frame = frame[mouth_y:mouth_y + mouth_h, mouth_x:mouth_x + mouth_w]

              # equalize frame dimensions
              frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.columns, self.rows)).astype('float32')

              # accumulate frames
              frames.append(frame)

            # ignore multiple facial region detections
            else:
                pass

        # equalize sequence lengths 
        if len(frames) < self.frames_per_sequence:
            frames = [frames[0]]*(self.frames_per_sequence - len(frames)) + frames
        frames = np.asarray(frames[0:self.frames_per_sequence])

        # pixel normalizer
        pix_norm = lambda frame: frame / 255.0

        samples_batch = [[map(pix_norm, frames)]]

        # random transformations for data augmentation
        for _ in xrange(0, self.samples_generated_per_sample-1):
            rotated_frames = random_rotation(frames, rg=45)
            shifted_frames = random_shift(rotated_frames, wrg=0.25, hrg=0.25)
            sheared_frames = random_shear(shifted_frames, intensity=0.79)
            zoomed_frames = random_zoom(sheared_frames, zoom_range=(1.25, 1.25))
            samples_batch.append([map(pix_norm, zoomed_frames)])

        return samples_batch

class ProgressDisplay(Callback):
    """ Progress display callback
    """
    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print "    Batch {0:<4d} => Accuracy: {1:>8.4f} | Loss: {2:>8.4f} | Size: {3:>4d}".format(int(logs["batch"])+1,
                                                                                                  float(logs["categorical_accuracy"]),
                                                                                                  float(logs["loss"]),
                                                                                                  int(logs["size"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example usage
    osr = OpticalSpeechRecognizer(rows=100, 
                                  columns=150, 
                                  frames_per_sequence=45, 
                                  samples_generated_per_sample=10, 
                                  config_file="training_config.json", 
                                  training_save_fn="training_data.h5", 
                                  osr_save_fn="osr_model.h5")
    # osr.process_training_data()
    osr.generate_osr_model()
    osr.print_osr_summary()
    osr.train_osr_model()
    osr.save_osr_model()
    osr.load_osr_model()
```

Introducing batch normalization seems to have caused the training loss to be NaN very quickly:[image]

Comment: What version of Keras are you using?

Comment: I'm using keras 1.0.7 from conda-forge

Comment: does it work without batch normalization?

Comment: @NassimBen yes, it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you introduce nan inputs into your network. For nan input you will get nan output. Do you by any chance have an input that is entirely 1 number? Then dividing through the variance is dividing through 0 -> nan inputs.

Edit:

You are using dim_ordering th. Therefore you want to batch normalize the axis 1. This has to be specified for the batch normalization layer. The default argument only works for tf dim_ordering.

Comment: There was actually a bug where batch normalization did this. This was fixed quite some time ago. Now it is `x/(var(x)+eps)` and does not suffer from division by zero anymore.

Comment: He is using an old version therefore it could still be the case.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz each sample is a sequence of image frames, where each frame pixel originally had a value range of 0-255, but I divided each of the pixels by 255, so the value range of each pixel is now 0-1.

Comment: The question is if you have empty frames.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz 1.0.7 has the fix already. I submitted it before the release of 1.0.5 so this is probably not the cause for his issue.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz the script only appends frames that are considered valid, if by empty frames you meant invalid frames.

Comment: @nemo does the batch normalization layer work for 3D convolution? If so, do I have to specify non-default values to the parameters to make it work?